# Losing changes when using git merge

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge

I'm somewhat new to git and I'm experiencing some unexpected results when I `git merge`. It appears that branch I'm merging FROM is changing, and this is not my understanding of how it should work.

Here's an example. I have two branches: master and new-branch. new-branch is ahead of master by several commits. Maybe I switch back to master to make a quick fix. Then I switch back to new-branch and I want that same fix from master to be applied. So (while in new-branch) I do:

`git merge master`

Now, should master have changed at all? I'm expecting only the changes from master to get applied to new-branch, but that doesn't seem to be happening. I keep loosing work and having to redo it and I cannot figure out why. Any advice?

Here's some `git log`:

```
ESL-MAC:sow3.dev $ git log
commit d30a517211c8663ab5cd28664d1b7ea59c82b248
Author: el
Date:   Fri Jan 11 17:18:44 2013 -0500

    fixed wsat page again

commit 31557a867585ac81b6fda33971d9ba16f1efafb9
Merge: 35af780 5ea9b23
Author: el
Date:   Fri Jan 11 17:10:22 2013 -0500

    replaced meta for get_wsat() in WSAT

commit 5ea9b233fb3d01c0dc9dfb5b0e48c80e8fb0eb58
Author: el
Date:   Fri Jan 11 16:50:06 2013 -0500

    removed admin bar AGAIN

commit 177d9ab8973c0e9f85a21ffad4ef6065cf6e9675
Author: el
Date:   Fri Jan 11 16:47:07 2013 -0500

:
```

Comment: Can you show some output (from `git log` for example) that shows what you're seeing?

Comment: .. and are you sure you don't want `git rebase master` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This much is certain. In git if you:

```
git checkout new-branch
```

...and then...

```
git merge master
```

...nothing on `master` should change. As I think you already know, you're asking git to merge any new commits from `master` into `new-branch`. If you're getting a different result, something is seriously wrong. Hard to know what, though as you say you're new to git my best guess is that you're not actually committing on master the way you think you are.

The simplest process for a commit would be:

Do some work...

```
git add path-to-file(s)
git status (not strictly necessary, but will confirm that you actually added what you think you added)
git commit -m "This commits the file(s) I just added"
```

As Edward notes, seeing a git log might be revealing.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks Marc. I'm using the exact commands you demonstrated. The only difference I can see is that I tend to use `git add -A` rather then git the exact path to the file. Would that change anything?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it shouldn't (I consider -A as a dangerous practice, but not for any reason to do with this discussion). Your commits in the git log look plausible enough. I'll ponder a bit and see if I can think what else might be causing your grief.

Comment: Thanks so much. And if you can direct me to discussions elsewhere re: -A I'd be curious to know more about it's riskiness. My problem is that many of my changes involve several different files, and it's cumbersome to add them each one by one. At the same time, I can't help but wonder if my overuse of -A is partly to blame for my troubles.

Comment: The "dangerous practice" to me is simply about adding random files (I don't do `git add .` either). I prefer to be more surgical, lest I get into a sloppy habit that results bloated commits and unnecessary conflicts. I'd be very surprised if this was causing your present difficulty, unless the unexpected "changes" in master are in fact random files you're committing without realizing it.

Comment: One thing you could try to assess the problem would be `git show d30a5172` where `d30a5172` is one of your commit hashes (the first 8 characters or so are sufficient). That will print the contents of a commit. If things look right, then probably you committed what you expected. But MAYBE there's more in the commit than you expected...or less. That might be instructive as to why things don't look the way you expect them to. Another thing would be to use a visualization tool like gitx (http://gitx.frim.nl/) to see what was committed and into which branch. It'll also visually explain merges.

Comment: If I branch off the master and make three commits on new-branch. Then I checkout master and make a commit ("A") on master. Then I do `git merge new-branch`. Unless there's a direct conflict between the commit on new-branch, should I expect commit "A" to be preserved on master branch after the merge?

Comment: I feel like there must be something wrong with what I'm doing, but other than over-using `git add -A` to save time I can't think what it is. I commit very often and after specific changes, so I don't think `-A` should be a problem, but maybe I'm over-looking something.

Comment: One more important detail: I basically never have to resolve conflicts. I commit and merge often enough that it's basically a non-issue.

Comment: Your description of the workflow (3 comments up) is correct, and yes, the git log of master based on your description would be (oldest) new-branch commit 1 > new-branch commit 2 > new-branch commit 3 > master commit 1 > merge commit (newest).